# Selecting a flyback diode

Tags: mosfet, diodes, flyback, solenoid, logic-level

According to the schematic below , where J15 connects to solenoid B11HD-255-B-3 and solenoid B11HD-255-B-3 is rated 19V, 90W, what is the technical approach to selecting a flyback diode? (D15) I have also seen general and zener diodes oriented in opposite directions across the solenoid. Is this arrangement recommended here and why?
[image]

Added background - this is a MOSFET driven solenoid circuit, logic level, and I have tested this circuit with a random guess diode (onsemi model S1B) with success. In the test circuit, I used 24V and B11HD-254-B-3 (36W version). Moving up to the 90W, I want to be more thoughtful and deliberate with my design.

[image]

Comment: What’s the peak relay current your are expecting? That and voltage rating.

Comment: Hi, the voltage is 19V and at 90W each will pull 4.7 amps. I don't think there is appreciable inrush current for DC solenoid coils.

Answer (score 4):

The peak diode current is predictable from the information sheet- it will be a bit less than 5A- the same as the steady-state solenoid current. It will decay from that value more-or-less exponentially with an L/R time constant. It only needs to be rated for the supply voltage plus some safety margin. If you are using ordinary rectifiers there is no significant penalty in using a 400V or 600V-rated part rather than a 50V part (and it’s more likely the higher-voltage part number will be useful elsewhere).

What is not given is information that would allow us to predict the exact duration of the pulse since we don’t know the inductance of the coil (and, in fact, it may vary significantly if the magnetic circuit changes as a result of things moving- which it normally does).

That said, I would expect a 3A rated diode would suffice. It should run cool unless you’re rapid-firing the solenoid. You can measure the duration magnitude of the current with a current sensor and an oscilloscope to confirm.

The reason to use zener diodes and similar things is to work the transistor and diodes harder, and in exchange for stressing those parts more the solenoid drops out faster (pull-in is unaffected). That’s because more of the energy stored in the inductance is dissipated in the zeners (which requires the transistor to block more voltage and stresses the transistor more as it turns off.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. When you say rapid-firing, how fast do you mean PWM fast or 10Hz fast? These may be fired approx. 10 times a second. I have an oscilloscope - Siglent SDS1104X-E and DAQ - LabView USB-6000. What sort of setup can I use to measure the current and duration? Do I add a shunt current resistor in series with the solenoid and scope the voltage drop across it?

Comment: Also, faster solenoid drop out, does that mean the solenoid pull force stops faster after the voltage is zeroed and the return spring can return the plunger faster? That is actually very attractive to me. I would like to explore fast drop out options.

Comment: The maximum power total power dissipation is probably at close to PWM but won’t be more than about half the steady-state- so about what you’d get for 2.5A DC. I would get a LEM non-contact sensor - just thread the wire through the sensor. You could try a shunt, which is cheaper but there is more room for artifacts and error because of added resistance and small amounts inductance that may have a lot of impedance compared to a low value shunt. If you use a low inductance shunt, aim for maybe 300-500mV drop it would probably be fine. You’re not looking for precision measurements.

Comment: Yes, in general to make the solenoid drop out somewhat faster you allow the voltage across the coil to rise as much as possible, hundreds of volts potentially. To make it pull in faster you would feed it with something approaching a constant current source (potentially, again, rising to hundreds of volts when first applied). Of course these reduce the effect of inductance by causing f to rise and fall as quickly as possible, but always f=ma and it can’t work magic. One place where it matters is in ICE fuel injectors.

Comment: Thanks I am going to get a LEM.

Comment: So if cost and durability were thrown out the window, what would be the fastest drop-out configuration? I saw others discussing this regarding this item LM1949 and it was suggested to simply sink the inductive kickback to ground with a Zener diode. I don't think my MOSFET is avalanche rated adequately so that option is out. Thoughts on the Zener to ground instead of looping it back into the coil?

Comment: Aside from a mechanical contact, probably a high voltage (so likely not logic-level at the gate) MOSFET with a diode + Zener in series across the coil. Diode + resistor is also a possibility.

Comment: Yes, the opposing zener and diode appears to be the fastest option. Now I am burdoned by the 30V breakdown rating of the MOSFET. I don't think letting the voltage exceed 20V is a great idea so the zener benefit is zeroed if the zener voltage does not exceed Vcc correct?

Comment: If the Zener is across the coil then it (plus a diode drop) adds to Vcc for the MOSFET rating. You can get a higher voltage MOSFET, but for >60V or so you might need to add a gate driver.

Comment: I am considering a switch to this MOSFET - Vishay model SIS176LDN-T1-GE3; it is 70V and switches easily with 3.3V. pretty sweet! Now I am looking for diodes. ACZRC5366B-G for the zener and ACZRC5366B-G for the general are looking good. I also purchased an LCR meter on amazon to determine the coil inductance. I believe progress is in progress; thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The current through the diode will will have a peak of 5.5 A, one should choose a diode which supports a direct current of at least 6 A.

Inductance is not essential, as the peak current stays below 6 A for values between 0.01 H and 1 H of the solenoid.

However, if the diode on the solenoid fails, the inverse voltage in the circuit will reach 550 V when the driver cuts off the current (depending on speed). Therefore, I would put a fast, 6 A flyback diode protection on the driver as well.

Also, if the wires to the solenoid, which have their own inductance, are longer than 1 m one should take into consideration having a diode close to the solenoid, and another one close to the circuit board.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your input. What would a flyback on the switch look like? It would need to be a zener?

Comment: In this particular case of use, a zenner diode does exactly the same thing as a fast regular or Schottky diode, so it's not wrong, neither mandatory, to use one. Example parts: RB606, RB608, RB610, P600J, P600K, P600M, MR756, MR758, MR759,  IDH08S60C, IDV03S60C, C3D04060F, C3D04060A, C3D03060F, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome Mike: Potential problem, you are feeding the MOSFET with a voltage divider, this will reduce the capacity of the MOSFET and cause it to operate warmer.  Since R36 is a used to guarantee the state during microprocessor reset etc it should go on the port of the micro, not the gate. I would use a schottky diode, with a 19V supply 50V would be OK. The inductive load will return the current it is charged with so you need to be able to support that current pulse. This can be found in the pulse category of the diode data sheet.  You need to rate the diode voltage for your load voltage, as the flyback voltage will be limited to the forward drop of the diode.

Comment: Hi Gil, thank you for your input. Are you suggesting placing R36 between the micro output pin and ground? The 150 Ohm resistor limits the current from the micro to the MOSFET gate to about 20mA based on others' suggestions. My intention here is to protect the micro. Please let me know if I am understanding that part properly. Then, for the inductor kickback, my MOSFET is rated 30V so I'm afraid I am limited with respect to the voltage. An opposing zener and diode parallel to the solenoid sound like a great option (with a zener voltage of 40V) but its not possible based on my MOSFET ratings.

Comment: You are correct, and I would suggest changing the 150 to about 50. There is generally no reason to limit the current in the MOSFET gate, that just slows it down allowing it to stay in the linear region and get hotter. Generally that resistor is to protect the microprocessor not the MOSFET. Check your data sheet on the micro and you will find you are OK with the lower value resistor. Realize when the gate voltage reaches the driver voltage there is no current flowing (pico amps maybe). That current just drives the gate capacitance. The schottky diode is fast enough to protect the MOSFET.